# JList getSelectedValue()

Tags: java, swing, jlist

[image]

Hello there. I have done a thorough search on google how to get the selectedValue in the JList and use the value to calculate the price of the menu, as shown below in the figure. However, I can't figure out a way to implement the button Calculate feature. Please see the image below for the description of the problem.

```
    import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JResto extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField t1;
    private JButton b1;
    private JList list;
    private String[] values = {"Fried Rice (Rs 150)", "Fried Noodle (Rs 125)", "Chop Soy (Rs 75)", "Wang Tang (Rs 35)"};

    public JResto(){
    super("Sumen Restaurant");
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 440);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblSumenRestaurant = new JLabel("Sumen Restaurant");
    lblSumenRestaurant.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    lblSumenRestaurant.setBounds(156, 11, 127, 29);
    add(lblSumenRestaurant);

    list = new JList(values);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    list.setBounds(115, 52, 200, 129);
    add(list);

    JLabel lblQuantity = new JLabel("Quantity");
    lblQuantity.setBounds(115, 225, 46, 14);
    add(lblQuantity);

    t1 = new JTextField();
    t1.setBounds(171, 222, 86, 20);
    add(t1);
    t1.setColumns(10);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Calculate");
    b1.setBounds(171, 304, 89, 23);
    add(b1);

    b1.addActionListener(this);

}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){





    }
}
```

Comment: You want us to do your homework ?

Comment: It looks like you want a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show your revised approach if you still have problems.

Comment: @NeerajJain Bous ou liki ! Its not a homework.

Comment: @trashgod The problem lies in the actionPerformed.. unable to get value from the JList

Comment: The problem will lies when there is something in `actionPerformed` , there is nothing out there man !

Comment: `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  
  int qty = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
  
  if(list.isSelectedIndex(0))
   total = qty * 150;
  else if(list.isSelectedIndex(1))
   total = qty * 125;
  else if(list.isSelectedIndex(2))
   total = qty * 75;
  else if(list.isSelectedIndex(3))
   total = qty * 35;
  
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total price of the menu is " + total);
  
  `

Comment: @NeerajJain It now works ! :D

Comment: you should have posted code in your Post

Comment: I posted it :D 

Vote me up :D :D

Answer (score 1):

The code now works !

managed to do it with `list.isSelectedIndex()`

Answer (score -1):

you can use jlist item with the methode add

list = new JList(values); // not used eny more and will dispare soon